# "This document could not be autosaved"

Tags: texshop

I am editing some latex documents from my university's online repository, and when I modify them and try to compile the message "This document could not be autosaved" appears and the changes do not appear in the pdf.

I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: My guess would be that your editor is trying to save in a directory where you don't have write permission.

Comment: And how do I get write permission?

Comment: this is off topic here (it is just about your local institution filesystem policy) but probably you need to save the file to your area rather than leave it in the general shared folder, but really we can only guess.

Comment: I can't tell you without more information. What editor are you using? Where is it trying to save the files? What happens if you try to save the files yourself?

Comment: @David Carlisle If this is off-topic, where can I ask the question?

Comment: @Ian Thompson I am using Texshop.

Comment: ask the administrators of your local university filesystem.  But just copy the file to your local area, just as if you were copying code from this site you would save it to your folder not your universities shared area.